# remove index.php from url in laravel in ubuntu

Tags: mod-rewrite, ubuntu, url-rewriting, laravel

I have tried several ways to remove index.php from my URL.

problem like

url not working(i want this): http://mysite.in/our-story

url working(i don't want this): http://mysite.in/index.php/our-story

1) I have tried to enanble rewrite_mod but it is already enabled.

2) I have tried to this code into .htaccess file but problem is not solved.

> Options -MultiViews
>       RewriteEngine On
>
> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule ^ index.php [L] </IfModule>
> ```

any file installation is remaining?? then tell me?? (but i have installed everything.)

my 000-default file is:

> ```
>     ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
>
>     ServerName mydomain.in
>
>     DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite/public
>     <Directory />
>             Options FollowSymLinks
>             AllowOverride None
>     </Directory>
>     <Directory /var/www/mysite/public/>
>             Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
>             AllowOverride None
>             Order allow,deny
>             allow from all
>     </Directory>
>
>     ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
>     <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
>             AllowOverride None
>             Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
>             Order allow,deny
>             Allow from all
>     </Directory>
>
>     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
>
>     # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
>     # alert, emerg.
>     LogLevel warn
>
>     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
>
> Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
> <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
>     Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
>     AllowOverride None
>     Order deny,allow  Deny from all
>     Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
> </Directory>
> ```

Please give me solution for that.

thanks friends!!!

Comment: Change `AllowOverride` to `all` instead of `none`.

Comment: Right sir.............

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change AllowOverride to all instead of none.

by Jason Lewis

Answer (score 0):

Check if .htaccess permissions are set to www-data (or corresponding Apache user)